BehaviorSubject does not update when called from app.config.ts
TL;DR - Solution:
I was using subscribe rather than pipe the value to the APP_INITIALIZER. Also, I was registering twice UserService, once as a singleton (which it should be) and second time within the Header component it self, which basically was a new instance of UserService.
=======================
I'm calling my UserService from app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (userService: UserService) => {
        return () => userService.getSessionMock();
      },
      deps: [UserService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
};

UserService:
  public user$ = new BehaviorSubject<AuthUser | null>(null);

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  public getSession() {
    return this.http
      .get<SessionUser>('https://localhost:7298/api/auth/session', {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .subscribe((user) => {
        (user as AuthUser).isAuthenticated = true;
        this.user$.next(user as AuthUser);
      });
  }

This doesn't work even when I'm using a mock of a user.
It works when I run the code from ngOnInit on the component itself.
HeaderComponent which uses the data:
export class HeaderComponent {
  userService: UserService = inject(UserService);
  currentUser$ = this.userService.user$;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser$.subscribe((user) => console.log(user));
  }
}

header.component.html
<div *ngIf="currentUser$ | async as currentUser">
            <a href="https://localhost:7298/api/auth" *ngIf="!currentUser.isAuthenticated">
                <button class="bg-white text-cyan-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-full">Login</button>
            </a>
            @if(currentUser.isAuthenticated) {
            <span>{{currentUser.name}}</span>
            <a href="https://localhost:7298/api/auth/logout">
                <button class="bg-white text-cyan-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-full">Logout</button>
            </a>
            }
        </div>

getSessionMock
public getSessionMock() {
    this.user$.next(mockUser);
 }


please share the code of getSessionMock

Naren Murali, added! :) (mockUser is just a dummy object)

Could you try my answer instead? app_initializer won't work with this method!

Oh my apologies, I didn't see you're the same one who commented, I did try it with getSession rather than getSessionMock, using the same code you commented (made sure I'm returning an Observable) but it didn't work

FWIW: Please don't put solutions inside a question, rather post an answer

You have to return the observable and not subscribe to it, also you can use tap to perform side effects inside the stream.
Only then the user$ will be initialized before the application loads.
 public user$ = new BehaviorSubject<AuthUser | null>(null);

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  public getSession() {
    return this.http
      .get<SessionUser>('https://localhost:7298/api/auth/session', {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .pipe(
        tap((user) => {
          (user as AuthUser).isAuthenticated = true;
          this.user$.next(user as AuthUser);
        })
      );
  }

Also why are you calling getSessionMock shouldn't it be getSession.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (userService: UserService) => {
        return () => userService.getSession();
      },
      deps: [UserService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
};


It doesn't work, it did work for a second I'm not sure why but I saw in Network 2 calls to the same endpoint, now it doesnt work. I'm using Tap (it says it'll be deprecated therefore I did not use it initially) pipe fn

@xarielah For the two APIs go to network tab and check the initiator tab of each API to see where it gets called twice. THen what do you mean by not working, is the behaviour subject not having a value?

Now it is only calling once, I'm unsure why it did it but I seem to not experience it again. From the initiator tab the current fetch is sources from main.ts which seems about right. I hjave managed to narrow it down - "Not working" meaning, I cannot render the user in my component / when subscribing to the user$ value from the component.ts (subscribing the stream from ngOnInit) or from within the html (piping it to async) it does not update

@xarielah Make sure UserService is set to providedIn: 'root' and is not added to any providers array in the application. also check this.userService.user$.value console.log in the component.

Thank you! you helped me! the service was indeed registered as root, meaning a singleton behavior but I also DID PROVIDE it for the header component it self, now I understand why it literally felt like a different instance of the service. THANK YOU!
